# How to load in a batch file?

Tags: batch-file, load, savechanges

I'm trying to make a .bat game and have most of the codeing already done.
I looked up how to have the player save and load and it told me to save with this

```
@echo SET ITEMS=%ITEMS%   >> savegame.cmd
```

So it would save on savegame.cmd
but how do i Load that information from savegame.cmd back to my .bat file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command you're using to save creates a .cmd file with the contents `SET ITEMS=<items>` where `<items>` is the current value of the ITEMS variable. To load this variable again, simply

`call savegame.cmd`

and the ITEMS variable will be set to the value stored in the samegame.cmd file.

Also, it's worth nothing that `>>` adds text to the end of the file while `>` writes a new file every time. If you think you're going to be saving a lot, it may be worth considering making the save command `@echo SET ITEMS=%ITEMS% > savegame.cmd`

Answer (score 1):

Also worth it to add a IF EXIST savegame.cmd ECHO "Do you want to overwrite a previous save?" ELSE @echo SET ITEMS=%ITEMS% > savegame.cmd